# Vue conditional event binding with arguments

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, conditional-statements, event-binding

I try to bind coditionaly an event method like

the template

```
 <div class="survey-card__option radio" :class="data.column ? data.column : ''"
                     v-for='(option, index) in data.options' :key="index">
                    <input type="radio" :name="form[data.id + '--' + fieldKey]"
                           :value="option.body"
                           :id="option.body"
                           v-on="{ change: data.hasButton ? watchChange(data, $event) : null }"
                           v-model="form[data.id + '--' + fieldKey]">&nbsp;
                    <label :for="option.body" class="survey-card__options__label">
                        <span>{{ option.body }}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

the listener

`v-on="{ change: data.hasButton ? watchChange(data, $event) : null }"`

and the method

```
watchChange(data, event) {
            console.log(event)//undefined
            console.log(data)
        }
```

I try to track the current value of the checked and match against json value and in case show some text.

The method will fire but I can't track the $event I get the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "$event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and cleaner to use the ternary in the listener instead?

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to define the the `$event` argument by yourself (use a arrow function for example):

```
v-on="{ change: data.hasButton ? ($event) => watchChange(data, $event) : null }"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
watchChange(event) {
    if(!this.data.hasButton)
        return;
    console.log(event)
    console.log(this.data);
}
```

Then you can bind it like this `v-on="watchChange"`

Comment: Thanks I gave a try but does not seems to work in my case

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that `data` was a data of your component